# Adding product using phpmyadmin to user

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, phpmyadmin

Im trying to add products through phpmyadmin to an existing order that has already been completed so that it shows up when I do a wc_customer_bought_product search in the php.

I have tried adding it to *wp_woocommerce_order_items* and *wp_wc_order_product_lookup* and that seems to get it to show up in the order but still not showing up in wc_customer_bought_product.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do that from the Woocommerce -> Orders -> Edit order page? There's a button below the order item list which let you add products via the UI.

If that doesn't work for some reason i guess it is still easier to make Woocommerce do that for you so that it updates all the related values it might need to work.

Something like this:

```
$productToBeAdded = wc_get_product(yourproductid);
$order = new WC_Order( yourorderid );
$order->add_product($productToBeAdded);
$order->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I ended up adding it for now using the Edit order page but it did mean  that I had to edit multiple orders one at a time. :) I am creating some code that when products get added to the site that is part of a pack it gets linked to the user (order) that is why Im trying to find where all the data gets stored but you have a good point with the code. Will give it a try Thanks

Comment: Upvote the answer or mark as accepted if it satisfy your needs ;)